# Plot circle that contains 80% (x, y) points

Tags: python, plot, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d-array (x, y) of points and I would like to plot a circle that contains the 80% of this points and also I would like to know the radius of the resulting circle. Is there any way to do this with python?

I've been looking for a way to do it but with no success. I apology for not presenting a try, but I'm totally lost with the condition of taking the 80% without giving a radius to the circle.

**Update:**

I've tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1, 1.15, 1.23, 0.92, 1.31, 1.18, 1.27, 1.07, 3, 3.2]

y=[1.17, 0.95, 1.04, 1.32, 1, 1.22, 1.28, 0.99, 1, 1.2]

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
circle=plt.Circle((1.1, 1.12), 0.2, color='g', fill=False)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.axis([0, 3.5, 0, 3.5])
plt.show()
```

And this is the plot I want to obtain:

[image: plot_I_want_to_obtain]

In this example I have 10 points and the circle is the minimum circle where 8 points are inside. I have done this example by eye, but what I want is: given x and y, get the parameters of the circle (the center position and the radius) that match the condition that at least 80% of points are inside it, i.e., how has to be the minimum circle that contains at least 80% of points. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the centre of the circle fixed, or do you need to determine it as well?

Comment: The centre of the circle is not fixed either. The only condition I have is that the circle has to contain the 80% of the points.

Comment: Are the points randomly distributed? I'm not even sure one can solve this problem generically. Imagine all the points being exactly on a circle - then it's either 100% of them in, or just any two of them.

Comment: This are my x and y: x=[-0.04319995 -0.07200006  0.21959993 -1.75320008 -0.76679997  0.66240005  0.62999999  0.62999999 -1.8576     -0.2808]; y=[-0.072    -0.05202  -2.26098  -2.661012 -2.35998  -0.993024 -3.162996   -3.07998  -3.375972 -1.174032]

Comment: @deets: That example isn't quite correct since the centre of the circle we are looking for isn't fixed (think http://www.georeference.org/forum/e41302F38333336302F636972636C65312E706E67/circle1.png)

Comment: @user2871248: Are you looking for at least 80%, at most 80%, exactly 80%, as close as possible to 80% (from above? from below?) etc?

Comment: @NPE: I'm looking at least 80% of the points to be inside of the circle

Comment: @user2871248 for --at least-- 80% just plot a circle around all of the points...

Comment: With all respect, there is an **infinity** of circles, that meet the said condition. There must be some more criteria defined.

Comment: @yurib: but if I have 2 points of 20 that are far away from the rest, I don't want them inside of the circle

Comment: @user3666197, NPE: you're right, I was confused, sorry. I'm looking for at most 80% of points inside of the circle, no more of them, because I don't want to consider those that are away from the most of them

Comment: still **infinity** of such circles. Some more criterie needed for un-ambiguous solution.

Comment: @user3666197: and if the condition is that the percentage of points inside the circle is as close as possible to 80% from bellow? then is only one solution possible, right?

Comment: Once you have a criteria to define the center of the circle (which you could define in many ways), the rest is easy, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by others, you could draw many different circles to obtain the requested result. But one quick and dirty way to do this might be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some random points
n = 1000
x = 4 * np.random.randn(n) + 15
y = 2 * np.random.randn(n) + 10

# somehow compute center of cloud, use e.g. medium or mean
x0 = np.median(x)
y0 = np.median(y)

# compute radius
r = np.sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2)
t = 80 # percent
r0 = np.percentile(r, t)
n_within = (r < r0).sum()

# make plot    
plt.plot(x, y, '.')
circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), r0, color='r', fill=False)
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.title('Found center at ({:.2f}, {:.2f})\n'
          '{}% radius is {:.2f}\n'
          '{} / {} points within circle'.format(
          x0, y0, t, r0, n_within, n))
plt.axis([0, 30, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because you are just looking to remove outlying points, this should work, but may do weird stuff with unusual data

Quick-n-dirty:

- For each point in the data set, calculate the average distance from each point in the data set to that point.
- Pick the point with the lowest average distance as the center of the circle.
- Take the distance to the farthest-away point from the center, and call that the radius.
- Shrink the radius until less than 80% of the points are inside the circle.

Alternate:

- For each point in the data set, calculate the average distance from each point in the data set to that point. Store this number, then sort the points based on it.
- Remove the top 20% from this list.
- Fit a circle around the remaining points.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking more of an algorithmic question than a python question.  And I'll say that this proposal is FAR from optimal but it might help you get started on the right path.

You could consider random search.  Select a random point and draw some number of circles of random radii with that point at the center.  Count the number of points in the circle and choose the best.

How many points you choose, how many circles you draw and at what radii depend on you.  The more you try the more likely you are to get as close to your 80% without going over.  What values you should try I can't possibly recommend any without some initial data exploration.  The more you try the more computationally expensive it will get.  It all depends on how important it is to get as close as possible to that 80% number.

Comment: You can do a contour integral for each point around the circle and count dTheta.  If a point is the in the circle the contour integral will evaluate to +/- 2pi (depending on direction of the integral), otherwise it will be zero