# plot a circle with some colored points in python

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot a circle with specified center position and radius and plot 100 random points between [0-500] which 80% of them in circle and 20% around with different colors.
To solve this problem I used [Plot circle that contains 80% (x, y) points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591762/plot-circle-that-contains-80-x-y-points) and customized based on my requirements but it's not working.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 100
low = 0
high = 500
x = np.random.random_integers(low, high, n)
y = np.random.random_integers(low, high, n) 
x0 = y0 = 250
r = 200
#t = 80 # percent
#r0 = np.percentile(r, t)
plt.plot(x, y, '.')
circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), r, color='black', fill=False, linestyle='--')
plt.plot(x0, y0, color='black', marker='^')
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.axis([0, 500, 0, 500])
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: In this code 80% of points is not in the circle. Also, I want to plot the points in two colors.

Comment: It is easy to place n points inside the circle because it is a finite region, but saying outside the circle is something irrational, they could all be at infinity, you could be more precise than it means outside for you, that is to say that those points are at a distance greater than the radius of 200 to another radius of 300 maybe.

Comment: why infinity? I have 100 points in [0-500] which 20% of them are out of circle. Also, your suggestion is good.

Comment: ok I understood, in a few moments to publish an answer.

Comment: So are you asking for an algorithm to determine the radius or something?

Comment: Or are you asking for how to generate 80 points within and 20 points outside a fixed circle?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear...

Comment: @eyllanesc. I'm very curious as to what it is that you understood. I don't understand what OP wants. Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: He wants to generate a graphic where 80 points are inside the radio circle 200 and another 20 that are between 2 circles of radius 200 and 500. In addition to having different colors.

Comment: Not necessarily between 2 circles. 20 points are just outside.

Comment: What does [0-500] indicate, is it a square or a circle?

Comment: Be concrete, one thing is to say approximately 20% and another thing is to say exactly 20%. The outside of the circle is impossible to solve since there is a way to obtain random numbers in infinite ranges, we must always delimit the ranges.

Comment: Exactly 20%. Is it possible to generate 80 points in circle and 20 points outside separately?

Comment: [0-500] is interval for axis.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my question. 
we can use the equation of circle to check the point is in the circle or not.

```
(x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2 < r**2
center:(x0, y0)
radius:r
```